# XSLT / XML: convert apostrophe to a space

Tags: xml, xslt

XSLT / XML: convert apostrophe to a space

My XML

```
<Name>KUEN'S INTERNATIONAL</Name>
```

USING XSL NEED TO CONVERT TO

```
<Name>KUENS INTERNATIONAL</Name>
```

In my xsl I have a template, where I am replacing the some special characters with spaces.

I need to replace `'` apostrophe from the string, which throws an error.

I even looked into some of the answers related with the issue, some have tried with version 2.0 but I am working in 1.0

Can you tell me how these special characters works -> <>&apos;
How to convert `'` apostrophe to space

```
<xsl:template name="stripSpecialChars">
    <xsl:param name="string" />    
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($string,'()*%$#@!~&lt;&gt;&amp;apos;,.?[]=-+/\',' ')"/> 
</xsl:template> 


<xsl:text><![CDATA[<NAME>]]></xsl:text>                         
   <xsl:call-template name="stripSpecialChars">
        <xsl:with-param name="string" select="/Name"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
<xsl:text><![CDATA[</NAME>]]></xsl:text>
```

Comment: &apos; is interpreted by XSLT as ' and &amp;apos; is interpreted as &apos;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another variable for that:

```
<xsl:template name="stripSpecialChars">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:variable name="stopset" select='"()*%$#@!~&lt;&gt;&apos;,.?[]=-+/\"'/>
  <xsl:value-of select="translate($string, $stopset, ' ')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

One line version

```
<xsl:template name="stripSpecialChars">
  <xsl:param name="string"/>
  <xsl:value-of select='translate($string, "()*%$#@!~&lt;&gt;&apos;,.?[]=-+/\", " ")'/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Or another param, then it's customizable... +1

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!! but one doubt why do we need add another variable ? we can give it in the same line right ? why it doesnt work there?

Comment: @VigneshLakshmanan: It does work with one line too, the trick is to use select='...' and then put enclosed strings in double quotes, see the edit

Comment: don't know what you mean, but `'` and `"` are interchangable in XML for exactly that reason, there's no escape characters, and the single version escapes the double version and vice versa